# How do i express this nftables command using firewalld rich rules, direct or policy method?

Tags: fedora, firewalld, nftables

I had issues with access to a service listening on the interface **lxcxxx** (172.XX). this because requests are arriving through  **eth0**, and firewalld was blocking the forwarding on the FWD filter

```bash
[30772.997987] filter_FWD_external_REJECT: IN=eth0 OUT=lxc24220340d98f MAC=96:00:01:a7:b1:a7:d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3:08:00 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX DST=172.20.4.140 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=43937 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41302 DPT=443 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

with this nftables command, the problem goes away:

```bash
nft add rule inet firewalld   filter_FWD_external_allow  iifname  "eth0" tcp dport { 80, 443, 25, 587}  accept
```

but of course it will disppear on reboot/ firewalld reload. How do i add something similar to firewall-cmd? I tried with rich rules, and policy, but im not sure whether its because of the lack of ordering in the tables, but the reject happens, here is something using the direct rules:

```bash
firewall-cmd --direct   --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD   1 -i eth0  -p tcp  --dport  443  -j ACCEPT
```

this does **not** work, the reject chain in  the firewalld table  is reached seemingly before this forward chain is reached. With the policy method i could not think of how to do this. Allowing masquerade also is insufficient.  How do i change the **filter_FWD_external_allow**  through firewalld so change persists?

Comment: Have you try to create a new table with your chains and rules ?
Firewalld use is own table so that should work if your table have a higher priority.

Comment: i ended up doing something like that.